# Как получить TreeViewItem из TheTreeView.SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

`TreeView` заполняется из класса, например такого

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

Когда я выделяю что либо в дереве, то в `TheTreeView.SelectedItem` находится экземпляр класса `MyClass`. А как мне получить именно `TreeViewItem`? Править класс я не могу (для того чтобы унаследовать его от `TreeViewItem`)

В поисках решений, нашел сразу 2 и оба не подошли

```
TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)(mainTreeList
    .ItemContainerGenerator
    .ContainerFromIndex(mainTreeList.Items.CurrentPosition));
```

`mainTreeList.Items.CurrentPosition` равен 0 всегда

```
TreeViewItem tvi = myTree.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(SelectedItem) as TreeViewItem;
```

`ContainerFromItem()` вернул null

Дополнение:

```
TreeGraph.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(TreeGraph.Items.CurrentItem)
```

Всегда возвращает первый элемент (с индексом 0).

Comment: `TreeView.SelectedItem` - возвращает текущий выделенный элемент. Делайте его каст до своего типа и работайте дальше

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь, расскажите, зачем вам нужно получать визуальный элемент из кода. Скорее всего нужную вам операцию можно сделать из разметки.

Если же нельзя, то `VisualTreeHelper` вместе с `LogicalTreeHelper` вам помогут добраться до нужного элемента.

**Обновление**

То, что вы хотите сделать, неправильно. Не надо из логики воздействовать на UI. И архитектуру приложения надо строить, исходя из этого принципа. Я думал, что вы из code-behind страницы пытаетесь получить нужный элемент.

Если же очень надо оперировать именно элементами, почитайте про `AttachedBehavior`, они навешиваются именно на визуальные контролы.

Comment: Каким образом VisualTreeHelper вместе с LogicalTreeHelper мне помогут? Что я передам в них в качестве параметра? Как я из своего невизуального класса смогу получить TreeViewItem?

Comment: Хорошо, тогда как, не воздействуя из логики на UI я могу осуществить выделение единственного элемента из двух разных контролов? В один момент времени можно выделить либо элемент из `TreeView` или элемент из `ListBox`. Не может быть два выделенных элемента. Если выделяю элемент на одном, то выделение на другом контроле снимается

Answer (score 1):

У меня при вызове `TreeView.SelectedItem` возвращался `object`
для использования его как TreeViewItem я использовал конструкцию

```
(TreeView.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem)
```

или

```
(TreeView.Items[index] as TreeViewItem)
```

не могу гарантировать что это однозначно правильный вариант использования, возможно это грязно, но у меня работало

Comment: У вас значит дерево заполняется объектами `TreeViewItem`. А у меня объектами типа `MyClass`

Comment: Ну тогда вы никак не получите `TreeViewItem` , если я правильно понял из ваших комментариев вы хотите снять выделение с элемента `TreeView` , когда выделяете что-то в `ListBox` , почему тогда нельзя сделать `TheTreeView.SelectedItem=null` ?

Comment: Потому что `TheTreeView.SelectedItem` доступен только для чтения